# Merging Extended partition with Unallocated Space: Error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 which is on a dual boot with Windows 7. I initially had 30 GB for Ubuntu ,but I decided I need more , now I booted Ubuntu from its Live CD ,used GParted , shrunk Windows partition by 50 GB ,so I got 50GB-unallocated space. Now I want to merge that with Ubuntu's partition (extended) . But I keep getting an "overlapping partition" error , and I am not able too identify where the overlapping is happening. Can anyone please help me out here ? /dev/sda4 is where my Ubuntu's 30GB extended partition is (which contains /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6) and /dev/sda3 is my Windows 7's partition. I have 50GB of Unallocated space between /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda4
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l -u

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6c48a710

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920    29044735    14481408    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        29044736   806342655   388648960    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       912336894   976771071    32217089    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       912336896   968585215    28124160   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       968587264   976771071     4091904   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63    31262489    15631213+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686668

Comment: did you move the unallocated space into the extended partition?Plz upload gparted screenshot and i will help you to extend your ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 1):

You might have encountered the following bug:

[Bug 686668 - Growing logical partition overlaps end of extended partition](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686668)

This problem was fixed in GParted version 0.14.1.

To use the latest version of GParted (currently 0.16.1), you might try booting your computer from media containing [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).